# How can I run UIautomator automation test in Firebase test lab by uploading already built external apk?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, automation, android-uiautomator

I have the code to run automation with gradle in android studio. But how can I upload already built/existing apk and run the UIautomator test? How ever I android studio gives me the option to run my code in firebase, **but I am not able to upload my external apk to the booked devices in firebase** and then run my automation. No code I have to upload and install the apk.

thank you.